# SimplePing working correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am launching Simple ping via a button push and then verifying that it worked via an arp dump. I've tried 3 different versions of the arp dump and come up with nil or 0 pending on the output. I am wondering if there is an issue with the way I am using ping or perhaps ping/arp combo only works on the phone?

Here is how I launch the simple ping:

```
NSString *NSip = @"10.0.0.7";

unsigned int UIip = [self StrIp2UnsignedLong:NSip];

SimplePing *sp = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:NSip];

[sp start];

int mac = dump(UIip);

[sp stop];
NSLog(@"Button Pushed %d", mac);
```

Comment: Setup a delegate, create the optional methods and verify the operation by logging the delicate calls.

Comment: @Zaph Funny typo. "delicate" should probably be "delegate".

Comment: Ah, autocorrect is such a ball of laughs! But do be delicate with your delegates. <sorry and I'm not even Canadian>

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @Zaph, so by your comment the simple ping is not actually running?

Comment: I don't know. It is a debugging problem, as such instrument as much as possible to find out more. The delegates are a good starting place. As much as I hate it there is "Wireshark" that will revel all network communications—terrible user interface but it will detail everything.